# how to fix Error in EER diagram to create tables?

Tags: mysql, diagram, workbench

when I wanted to generate tables, I got this error I don't know how to fix it. Is anyone face to this problem and how you solve it?

thanks

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_inv_detail` (
      `inv_id_fk` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `part_id_fk` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `qty` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL,
      `tb_detailed` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
      `tb_inv_detailcol` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`inv_id_fk`),
      INDEX `fk_tb_inv_detail_tb_parts1_idx` (`part_id_fk` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_tb_inv_detail_tb_parts1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`part_id_fk`)
        REFERENCES `tb_parts` (`part_id_pk`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_tb_inv_detail_tb_invoice1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`inv_id_fk`)
        REFERENCES `tb_invoice` (`inv_id_pk`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 25 succeeded, 1 failed

Also this screenshot of my EER diagram:
[image]

Comment: I would expect the create table being a single statement.  Are you sure that is the only thing you are running?

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious code which is missing from what you posted above is the DDL for the two tables referred to by the foreign keys defined in `tb_inv_detail`.  These tables are:

- tb_parts
- tb_invoice

These tables must be defined *first*, with correctly named primary key columns to match the foreign keys in your table above.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tb_parts (
    part_id_pk INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (part_id_pk),  -- referred to by part_id_fk
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE tb_invoice (
    inv_id_pk INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (inv_id_pk),   -- referred to by inv_id_fk
    ...
)
```